# Not interacting correctly in tab bar controller

Tags: swift3, uitabbarcontroller

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQH94.png)

I have problem with tabbar controller. When I inserted first menu icon, which is User Info, it does not correspond with tab bar controller.
Does anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks.